# CSS code issue when trying to replicate the BBC website

Tags: html, css

I am just starting out in web coding and am gettng  an issue with positioning of menu bar items when I trying to recreate the BBC website.  The menu options should go from right to left but are instead just being shows as a list which is on the same line as the logo and sign in section at the top.

I hope you can assist in telling me where I am doing wrong. Here is my jsbin code dump:

https://jsbin.com/wuteni/edit?html,output

Any assistance or tips will be most appreciated.

Comment: Would you be so kind to copy your code into the question? Think about how future readers will learn from this Q&A if that link breaks in six months time - it is best to have it as self-contained as possible. Adding the link _also_ is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#topmenudiv ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}

#topmenudiv ul li {
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

And to now have the images also in-line change HTML to:

```
<div id="topmenudiv">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/signin.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/bbclogo.png"/></li>
        <li> News </li>
        <li> Sport </li>
        <li> Weather </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there @smoggers, thanks for the help.  there is something else I missed out mentioning.  The menu list items need to be on the same line as the logo and the sign in sign.  Would you please be able to tell me how i can get it there.  Your last answer has helped greatly too.  Just this last part I need to do.

Comment: @PrashantVallabhbhai the easiest way would now be to just add the images inside the unordered list as fellow list items and that way they'd all be in-line with each other horizontally

Comment: tried this but it still does not move the menu list items to the top.

Comment: @PrashantVallabhbhai I added vertical-align:top; to the CSS above which now aligns them all in position

Comment: thanks a million. your solutions has solved my problem.  many thanks again for your help.